# Generating a XOR Hash function for a given group of numbers to maximise collisions

Tags: hash, keys, xor

Given $x$, a vector of $m$ distinct bit vectors of bit length $N$, I want to use an XOR-hash $h$ such that all $x_i$ collide to the same value.

I define an XOR hash $h$ which takes bit vector $q$ as input and performs an AND operation on each bit of $q$ with a bit vector $k_i$ of bit length $S$.

$h(q) = (k_1.q_1)\oplus(k_2.q_2)\oplus...\oplus(k_N.q_N)$

The "AND" dot operation $a.b$ takes bit vector $a$ and boolean/bit $b$ and returns ($a$ if $b$ else 0).

Here $k$ is a vector of bit vectors, and my goal is to find $k$ such that for some constant bit vector $y$ of bit length $S$, $h(x_i) = y$ for all $i$.

Section 4.3 in this paper describes this hash function. [http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~whalen/Hash/Hash_Articles/IEEE/Efficient%20hardware%20hashing%20functions%20for%20high%20performance%20computers.pdf](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Ewhalen/Hash/Hash_Articles/IEEE/Efficient%20hardware%20hashing%20functions%20for%20high%20performance%20computers.pdf)

It is my understanding that when you try to XOR-hash a bit vector of size $N$ to a bit vector of size $S$, there will be $2^{N-S}$ collisions. I want to choose $k$ so that all $m$ bit vectors in $x$ hash to the same value $y$.

For example, take $N=15$, and $m=200$.

I am trying to round $m$ to the next power of 2. In this case, I would like to round 200 to 256 and then have $2^{N-S}=256=2^8$, so that $N-S=8$ and thus $S=7$.

In other words, I can now XOR-hash from a $N=15$-bit space to a $S=7$-bit space with all the $m=200$ inputs colliding to the same output. I understand that there are an additional 56 numbers which are not accounted for. We choose any bit vector of size 15 which is not in $x$.

How do I go about finding $k$ deterministically (or closed-loop fashion) to make all the hashes collide?

Comment: Not exactly a clear question. What is $N(15)$? do you mean the number of bit o each $m$ us 15? then you should use $N=15$. Dou you hash $m_i$ with a cryptographic hash function then x-or the output? $$\bigoplus_{m=1}^{200} hash(m_i)$$

Comment: @kelalaka . Thanks for the advice. I have corrected the post accordingly. I am trying to generate a hash function which outputs the same value for all the m values. In other words $hash(m_0)$ = $hash(m_1)$ =$hash(m_{200})$

Comment: If the hash is a Cryptographic hash than it is an impossible task. However, once you find a collision, a multi-collision is much easier.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "using an XOR hash". XOR is not a hash algorithm. You can use XOR as one of operations when calculating hash. But describe what else are you doing to calculate hash.

Comment: @mentallurg I have added more detail to the question. I think this is call XOR AND or maybe it is called AND XOR. Cannot remember the full name.

Comment: @kelalaka The hash algorithm I am describing is a pretty poor performer in terms of collisions. I dont think it is a Cryptographic hash

Comment: k(i) is poor notation for bitvectors, maybe try subscripting? Anyway you claim the hash has a certain bit length, yet your hash function h(q) is guaranteed to output a single bit.

Comment: Is `m` a set of "binary numbers", a binary number, or the cardinality of a set of "binary numbers"? Also, numbers are numbers and bitvectors are bitvectors; why do you say "binary number"?

Comment: Wait is k a bitvector, a function, or what? You say k is a number but then possibly treat it as a function? Sorry you'll need to fix notation and wording on this question.

Comment: Is `k` an array of bitvectors each of bitlength S?

Comment: @AdrianSelf I have clarified the question and also included a link to the paper from where it came from. thx

Comment: @Acinonyx I have almost finished a revised version of the question. Can you explain the sentence starting "we choose any 17-bit..."? You say "any vector" but then "are" (single or multiple?) , and do you mean any bitvector of size 17 whose numerical equivalent is not among the m bitvectors? Ex if 010000000000010 in the m bitvectors than the bitvector of size 17 cannot be 00010000000000010?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110247/discussion-between-adrian-self-and-acinonyx).

Comment: @kelalaka The mapping is a linear transformation going from the input to the output.  Based on that can we adjust k such that the output is a known quantity.

Comment: It seems that choosing $k$ as the zero vector would cause the function to be the constant zero function (And thus all values would collide.) What am I missing?

Comment: Good point @Maeher, I think OP wants values not in x to hash to distinct outputs while values in x should collide?